# While consuming API Heavy data getting Aw snap error After Upgrade to V14, working fine in Angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript, xlsx, angular14

Hi We upgraded from Angular V9 to V14 recently. We are facing issue in loading JSON data and saving it as Excel. we are using below libs in package file..

"file-saver": "^1.3.8",
"@types/file-saver": "^1.3.0",
"@types/html2canvas": "0.0.36",
"@types/jspdf": "^1.3.3",
"@types/xlsx": "0.0.36",
"xlsx": "^0.18.5",

**2.Around 200 MB file saving fine in previous version of Angular 9. but now browser showing Aw snap issue. to save JSON data into Excel format we are using  "xlsx": "^0.18.5".**
In mozilla working fine. not sure what could be the issue.

please let me know if any idea.